# Javascript book which teaches javascript the language, not dom

Tags: javascript

I am a pretty good programmer(IMO only, of course. Know Python, Java well. Tried my hands at Lisp, Ruby, Haskell). I also know how to use Jquery reasonable well, so I know Dom manipulation.

I want a recommendation on a Javascript book, which teaches the Language. My criteria are,
1. Fast paced and for programmers who know programming. Dont tell me what loops are.
2. Teaches the language not the Dom manipulation.
3. Preferable ebook. Non free is fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript: The Good Parts.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it. JavaScript The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford is THE book to get if you are familiar with programming and other langauges.

Comment: There are other great JavaScript books, but almost all of them focus on JavaScript in the browser environment--meaning DOM work.

Answer (score 6):

Like others I'd firstly recommend JavaScript the good parts. Another option to consider is JavaScript the definitive guide by David Flanagan. This is also a good book that covers the language well- certainly enough depth for a programmer interested in particular features of javascript. The language part is seperate from the client side stuff- so you can just read the bits that interest you.

Update- I've just checked the book on Amazon it has a whopping 286 customer reviews!

Comment: 'The definative guide' is where it's at.

Answer (score 1):

Another good one is "Pro Javascript Design Patterns" by Harmes & Diaz. It starts by showing a number of approaches for simulating classes, classical inheritance, private members, etc., then builds on that to implement several of the more common design patterns seen in other OO languages. Some of the examples do involve the DOM, but they really give a feel for the flexibility of the core language.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few excellent JavaScript books for various levels.

[image]